# Rearrange rows and columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to rearrange rows and columns as per the requirements.

I have data in tables as:

```
SBU_ID   FAC_ID   Month     Year    Venting   Combustion   Comments
 3001     4001      1       2009      5.31     207.11   ABCD
 3002     4002      2       2009     15.24      45.12       XYZ
 3003     4003      1       2010      8.56       5.00       PQRS
```

Required format:

```
                            Jan-2009             Feb-2009         Jan-2010
SBU_ID FAC_ID Metric      Result   Comment     Result  Comment   Result  Comment
3001   4001   Venting      5.31     ABCD        15.24   XYZ       8.56   PQRS
3001   4001   Combustion   207.11   ABCD        45.12   XYZ       55.00  PQRS
```

Please advice if this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: If you post code, XML or **sample data as tables**, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What **database**?? What **version**?? Those things are often vendor-specific and cannot be handled easily in standard SQL

Answer (score 1):

Google for **PIVOT/UNPIVOT** functions (if you're talking about *MS SQL*) or it's analogs for *Oracle* and other databases.

Answer (score 0):

At SQL Query level don't try to solve this.

Once the query returns all the rows, do this gimmick in your high level code, java or c or what ever.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know if you want to just show the data, or completely transform the table design?

Normally (in first case), you should perform a query (or series of queries) to retrieve particular results from your source data.

Getting the data in required format is not simple using simple query (you don't mention any particular DB Engine). To be honest, I don't even know if it's technically possible to create queries to present columns entries (Venting, Combustion) as rows (series of "group by"s maybe?) without writing a simple application to convert the data.